# Vue.js handling errors streaming RTSP with RTSPtoWebRTC by deepch

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, rtsp

I am currently building web app with Vue. This web app streams RTSP, which I get from underwater drones with cameras. Here is the code:
**
SidebarItem**

```
    <li>
      <a>{{ name }}</a>
    </li>
  


  export default {
    props: {
      name: String,
      url: String,
    },
  };
```

**Player**

```
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css">
  <div class="fullscreen-player">
    <div :id="elementId" />
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-container">
    <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
      <aside :class="['sidebar', { 'open': showSidebar, 'closed': !showSidebar }]">
        <div class="sidebar-background">
          <div class="sidebar-header">
            <p style="font-weight: bolder;"><i class="bx bx-current-location"></i> Bathyscaphe</p>
          </div>
          <hr class="rounded">
          <div class="select-container">
              <div><p style="font-size: 1.2vw; color: #e2e2e2; margin-bottom: 1vh;">Currently streaming:</p> {{ selected }}</div>
                <select class="custom-select" v-model="selectedDevice" @change="updateFilteredStreams">
                  <option id="mySelect" disabled value="">Select the drone</option>
                  <option v-for="device in devices" :key="device">{{ device }}</option>
                </select>
          </div>
          <hr class="rounded">
          <ul>
            <li v-for="(url, name) in filteredStreams" :key="name">
              <button class="sidebar-button" :name="name" :value="url" @click="handleStreamSelected(name)" :disabled="streamErrors.includes(name)">
                <sidebar-item :name="name" :uuid="name"></sidebar-item>
              </button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </aside>
      <toggle-button :show-sidebar="showSidebar" @toggle-sidebar="toggleSidebar"></toggle-button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
import RTSPtoWEBPlayer from "rtsptowebplayer";
import ToggleButton from './ToggleButton.vue';
import SidebarItem from './SidebarItem.vue';
import configData from './../../RTSPtoWebRTC/config.json';

export default {
  name: "PlayerVue",
  computed: {
    filteredStreams() {
      return Object.entries(this.streams).reduce((filtered, [name, stream]) => {
        if (stream.deviceNumber.toString() === this.selectedDevice) {
          filtered[name] = stream.url;
        }
        return filtered;
      }, {});
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      config: {},
      streams: {},
      showSidebar: true,
      devices: [],
      selectedDevice: '',
      filteredStreamsData: {},
      uuid: '',
      elementId: 'player',
      streamErrors: [],
      player: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleSidebar() {
      this.showSidebar = !this.showSidebar;
    },
    updateFilteredStreams() {
      this.filteredStreamsData = this.filteredStreams;
    },
    handleStreamSelected(uuid) {
      this.uuid = uuid;
      const server = "127.0.0.1:8083";
      const source = `http://${server}/stream/receiver/${uuid}`;

      this.player.destroy(); // Destroy the existing player

      const options = {
        controls: false,
        parentElement: document.getElementById(this.elementId),
        autoplay: true
      };
      this.player = new RTSPtoWEBPlayer(options);
      this.player.load(source);
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.config = configData;
    this.streams = configData.streams;
    this.devices = [...new Set(Object.values(this.streams).map((stream) => stream.deviceNumber))];
    this.selectedDevice = this.devices[0].toString();
  },
  components: {
    SidebarItem,
    ToggleButton
  },
  mounted() {
    const server = "127.0.0.1:8083";
    const uuid = "Japan";
    const source = `http://${server}/stream/receiver/${uuid}`;

    const options = {
      controls: false,
      parentElement: document.getElementById(this.elementId),
      autoplay: true
    };
    this.player = new RTSPtoWEBPlayer(options);
    this.player.load(source);
  },
  beforeUnmount() {
    this.player.destroy();
  }
};


  @import url("../assets/sidebar.css");

  .fullscreen-player {
  position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* fix scaling */
  }
```

**config.json: **

```
{ "server": { "http_port": ":8083", "ice_servers": [ "stun:stun.example.com:19302" ] }, "streams": { "Japan": { "deviceNumber": "Not Russia", "on_demand": true, "disable_audio": false, "url": "rtsp://admin:12345@95.154.86.198:554/" }, "Vladivostok": { "deviceNumber": "Russia", "on_demand": true, "disable_audio": false, "url": "rtsp://admin:12345@95.154.69.152:554/" }, "Khabarovsk": { "deviceNumber": "Russia", "on_demand": true, "disable_audio": false, "url": "rtsp://admin:12345@95.154.86.198:554/" } } }` 
I get RTSP urls from json. And here I face the problem that when the stream is borken: off, url is incorrect et.c. my screen gives me an error. How do I fix it? I want buttons to be disabled when the stream the are reffering to is not somehow working
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: SIPCC Failed to parse SDP: SDP Parse Error on line 1: End of line beyond end of buffer. setRemoteDescription common_shim.js:243 RTSPtoWEBPlayer rtsp-to-web-player.js:218 like this or: 2023/07/22 21:27:35 Stream Try Connect Vladivostok 2023/07/22 21:27:38 dial tcp 95.154.69.152:554: i/o timeout 2023/07/22 21:27:38 Stream Exit On Demand No Viewer 2023/07/22 21:27:40 Stream Codec Not Found in terminal
```

Ive tried

```
  async checkStreamStatus(url) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      return response.ok;
    } catch (error) {
      return false;
    }
  },
}
```

```
  filteredStreams() {
    return Object.entries(this.streams).reduce((filtered, [name, stream]) => {
      if (stream.deviceNumber.toString() === this.selectedDevice) {
        const streamStatus = this.checkStreamStatus(stream.url);
        filtered[name] = { url: stream.url, status: streamStatus };
      }
      return filtered;
    }, {});
  },
},
```

```
  <button class="sidebar-button" :name="name" :value="stream.url" @click="handleStreamSelected(name)" :disabled="!stream.status">
    <sidebar-item :name="name" :uuid="name"></sidebar-item>
  </button>
</li>
```

It appears that the streams may not return a proper response when checked using the fetch method as fetch works with HTTP-based responses and may not handle RTSP stream statuses.